# Login sometimes does not work across tabs/windows in django

Tags: django, flash

I wish to login into a django based website from a secondary window.
i.e. I have a flash file connecting to a django server. On selecting login in the flash file it opens another window (namely the Facebook login popup). Facebook client based login flow is used to log the user in and the user_id obtained from this is sent to django server for identification and logging in.
I have verified on the server that at this stage, authenticate and login function of django.contrib.auth are called and user.is_authenticated() returns True.

But on the client side in the original window containing the Flash file, the user sometimes remains AnonymouseUser i.e. not logged in. At other times, the user is identified correctly.

On checking the database entries for current sessions, I see that when the user does not get logged in, there are two sessions present, whereas when the user gets logged in there is only one session.

I am not sure why one extra session gets created and how to remedy this.

Note - I am using a custom authentication Backend.

**UPDATE**
I dug into the django system to see what was happening.
Django has a mechanism to change the key for a session while maintaining the data.
What happens in my case is that the change in session key takes place twice. Once it occurs as expected during the login. But immediately following this, another request causes the session key to change. This request is not made by me in my client code. 
It seems the request is for /favicon.ico
Not sure where this originates from. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 2**
It definitely seems related to favicon.ico
Now that I am serving it at root, things function properly after a few refreshes. I think that the problem occured previously as the browser's request for favicon was messing up the session, when it was failing. I will test some more before confirming and closing this issue.

**UPDATE 3**
Not solved. I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.
Until then I will see if I can change the login flow to bypass this mechanism.

**UPDATE 4**
So after going through some stack traces(which I can share if required), I realized the following. Since Django changes a session id when logging in a user, it creates a situation where one session id gives rise to two session ids as follows.
Request 1 - An ajax request causing the login. This request has the session key previously provided by django, say key1. In response the server sends back a new session key, say key2 while deleting key1 from its memory (in my case database)
Request 2 - This is the implicit request that is made by the browser after the Request 1 for favicon.ico. (As you might know this request is made by the browser and I cannot control it)
This request also comes with the sam original key namely, key1. Since this key is not available in the memory for Django, it creates a new key, key3 and sends back in the  response.

As a result all further requests are made with key3, which django identifies with a new session and the logged in state stored with key2 is lost.

I am not sure whether this is a bug in Django or if this is the intended behavior.
But if this is an intended behavior it will create problems when any client makes multiple ajax requests before waiting for previous response and the key-change is triggered.

Having said this, my original problem remains and I will post a solution if and when I find one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have applied for now is to make multiple, as of now 2, calls to the login url. 
This means that if things work as explained above in update 4, the second login request will go with key3 and will receive key4. But since there is no other concurrent request from my code or browser, this key will remain and the user will always get logged in.
So far seems to be working, after 2 days of testing.

But my solution is a workaround, I would still like to know if this is a bug in django or there is something wrong in my code logic.